# UITableView dynamic grouped cells

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I've created this settings `tableview` using static cells and grouped style:

[image]

I'd like to recreate the same `tableview` but this time I'd like to use **dynamic** cells. I know how to work with dynamic cells but I don't know how I can set different sections with different headers.

I need 4 section (status, queue, type, severities) and each section has indefinite number of cells (the number is equal to the length of the array of data obviously).

Can someone post a complete example please? I couldn't find any documentation that could help me.

Comment: @Orions thanks you, I'll try this

Comment: @Orions The provided tutorial is not related to question OP is asking. It is about dynamic cells and doesn't talk about section headers or the title of section headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code [TableViewDemo](https://github.com/jeetendra-choudhary/TableViewDemo.git) You basically have to use below two methods.

```
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 4
}
```

and this for title of header -

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "your title" // Use the titleForHeaderInSection index
}
```

Comment: I only use these two methods for the tableview?

Comment: Ok is it not populating the sections as you wish can you post the code so that we can look into it?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `titleForHeaderInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let section = ["section1", "section2"]
let cellsInSection = [["section1cell1", "section1cell2"], ["section2cell1", "section2cell2"]]

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return section.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellsInSection[section].count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
return section[section]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("section1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SectionOneTableViewCell

        return cell
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("section2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SectionTwoTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris, I'll try this way.

Comment: I edited some codes just now. make sure you use the updated one. and let me know if that answered your question